# What is the difference between web/template and web/templates

Tags: magento2, template, uicomponent, html, component

I've noticed in the core both `web/template` and `web/templates` are used:

- `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/group/group.html`
- `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html`

Is this a mistake or is there a reason why there are two different directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singular `template` is the standard directory.

Despite the quantity of files in the Magento_Ui `templates` directory, that case appears to be a unique instance and why it was done that way is not clear to me. The Magento_Ui module appears to be the only module that uses `web/templates` instead of `web/template`. There is a `requirejs-config` entry that maps `template` to `templates` like so:

```
'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
```

(source: `module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js`).

The file (`module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/template/loader.js`) that handles the async requests for templates has a `formatPath` method which returns:

```
 return result.replace(/^([^\/]+)/g, '$1/template')
```

Consequently, if you use `template` as the directory, you can be less explicit in loading HTML templates, or you must map it.

For a concrete example of a core module using the `template` directory, refer to the `Magento_Checkout` module which has a large number of `.html` templates in the `web/template` directory.

---

The map was part of one of the first commits: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/0865a13d4785221cec11f343ddc3452a77014951/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js. It would not surprise me if the `template` was standardized and Magento_Ui was never updated.

Comment: I agree with your statement `template was standardized and Magento_Ui was never updated.` As always thanks for the good info.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a mistake, they have intentionally placed both folders, default one as we have seen for other modules is "template", however they have mapped the 'templates' folder in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js`
as following:

```
paths: {
        'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
    }
```

and they have used this mapped path as following:

```
'text!ui/template/tooltip/tooltip.html'
```

in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/tooltip.js` at line 11 in defined section.

The other way to access the template files from 'templates' folder can be seen in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js` at line 13 as `'text!Magento_ui/templates/grid/cells/thumbnail/preview.html'`

Also please note that the template files from this folder are actually used to render the html so it can be used, like to show the rendered html in a popup model. The rendering is achieved by feeding the template and its variables as arguments to `mage/template` class.